# Properly using Core Data

Tags: ios, core-data

I am learning about Core Data and persistency, however I am a bit confused. I searched around and couldn't find the right way to do it.

Lets say I want to store a object called Student. It has a few attributes: Name and ID.

My question is: Do I need a Student class to implement all the methods I want it to have? And then store this instance.

Or should I just create a category of the Student subclass of NSManagedObject generated by XCode to do all I wanted to?

Student has to be a singleton as I only need one instance of it and it has to accessible in all my views.

EDIT:
So as an example, if I want to instantiate a Student, am I right?

```
[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Student" inManagedObjectContext:context]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a subclass. Look at using [mogenerator](http://rentzsch.github.io/mogenerator/) to help you manage the model based content and your custom methods.

Don't add any properties to the class that aren't defined in the model, that will only cause you problems.

Remember that the methods you add can't be used in queries on the data store (fetch requests, with predicates / sort descriptors). Only the model properties can be used for that.

Comment: So as an example, if I want to instantiate a Student

[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Student" inManagedObjectContext:context];

Comment: Yes, `Student` would usually be the name of the model item and the class. Let mogenerator do the hard work on that. Then when you create and insert an entity it will return an instance of the `Student` class to you.